# In Postgres what are consequences of using "char" as external data type

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

What are potential consequences when using `"char"` data type for user table as external data type. I'm talking about `"char"` (note quotes) 1 byte internal data type which apparently can be used as external data type as well.

I want to store just one character so I see no reason to use char(1) which occupies 2 bytes if the same can be stored in `"char"` which occupies 1 byte.

The documentation lists `"char"` as internal data type but pgAdmin allows creating user table columns with this data type.

Comment: Is that extra byte really going to matter?

Comment: Doesn't char(1) actually take 5, not 2 bytes? `select pg_column_size('t'::char(1))` gives me 5.

Comment: @ Lukasz, If I recall, the manual says that overhead for strings is 1 extra byte for strings up to 126 bytes and 4 bytes for longer strings, but I didn't check the actual size on the disk. However if char(1) is really 5 bytes then there is even more reason to use "char".

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński: `char` is a different type than `"char"`. `select pg_column_size('t'::"char")` returns `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"char"` can be used in Postgres as external datatype however since it is designed as an internal datatype there is no guarantee that it will be compatible with future versions of Postgres. Rhodium Toad stated on the IRC chat that there is low likelihood that `"char"` will be eliminated anytime soon but also stated that potential gain from using it will be ignorable small due to padding.